# Como convertir o imprimir mi variable de minutos a días horas y minutos con php

Tags: php

espero se encuentren bien.

Estoy teniendo inconvenientes en mi proyecto de la universidad.
Tengo la siguiente variable en php:

```
<?php
$tiempototal = $minutos;

//Resultado = 2103 minutos.

//Como puedo hacer para imprimir esa variable de $tiempototal de esta forma: 1 día 11 horas 05 minutos 


?>
```

Yo esto lo hago pero de esta forma:

```
<?php

                $hif = new DateTime($horainif);//fecha inicial
                $hfhi = new DateTime($horafinf);//fecha Final

                $intervalof = $hif->diff($hfhi);


echo $intervalof->format('%ad, %H h %i m'); 

//Y eso me da como resultado = 5d, 00 h 40 m

?>
```

Como puedo hacer lo mismo pero para el primer ejercicio? seria convertir los minutos a ese formato de días horas y minutos.

Cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar me seria de gran utilidad.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

se guardan los dias horas y minutos en los valores del array

```
function calcMinutes($minutes)
{
    $time = ['days' => 0, 'hours' => 0, 'minutes' => 0];

    while ($minutes >= 60) {

        if ($minutes >= 1440) {

            $time['days']++;
            $minutes = $minutes - 1440;
        } else if ($minutes >= 60) {

            $time['hours']++;
            $minutes = $minutes - 60;
        }
    }

    $time['minutes'] = $minutes;

    return $time;
}

$minutes = 2103;
$timeFormatt = calcMinutes($minutes);
echo 'dias:'. $timeFormatt['days'] . ', horas:' . $timeFormatt['hours'] .', minutos:' . $timeFormatt['minutes'];
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono perfectamente.